# Does loading scripts at the bottom of a page guarantee the DOM will be ready before any script execution take place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

As suggested here, http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-3-events-ajax/, is loading scripts at the bottom of a page just before the closing body tag a very reliable way of knowing that the DOM is ready?

Comment: My understanding was that the benefit of loading scripts just before the closing `</body>` tag was to ensure the HTML/page rendering was completed before executing the scripts, so as to minimise the time it takes to display content to the user

Comment: No. Its best practice to add any script that relies on being available during dom using the onload event

Comment: Loading scripts at end of html is "perceived" performance. The script still will execute and lock the dom, the only difference is the visuals are available.

Comment: @cgatian sorry if I was unclear, but I think that is what I meant - it will mean that the user 'sees' a page as soon as possible, but not necessarily when the page has finished loading/executing all scripts

Comment: @Alfie yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise comments above:

Loading scripts at the bottom of the page is not a reliable way of knowing that the DOM is ready. As suggested by @cgatian, using an `onload` or `document.ready` event is better for this.

The typical benefit of loading scripts just before the closing `</body>` tag is to ensure the HTML/page rendering is completed before executing the scripts, so as to minimise the time it takes to display content to the user: this means that the user 'sees' a page as soon as possible, but not necessarily when the page has finished loading/executing all scripts.

Comment: `onload` is a very good candidate except for its obvious limitation of allowing only one listener per the event. `onload` in particular isn't executed until every asset has been loaded. A more efficient way will be to use the DOM Level 2 event model syntax to register listeners for the DOMContentLoaded event `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);`. And by `document.ready`, are you referring to the jQuery `$(document).ready()` idiom?

Comment: I suppose it depends on your context, afaik `DOMContentLoaded` is only compatible with IE9+; if this isn't a problem, it sounds a good option, but with regards to your original question, deferring script loading is not equivalent to a 'dom loaded check'. And yes @ jquery/document.ready .. sorry for the lack of clarification there

Comment: Well grasped. The safest approach is to perform a dom ready check. Ughh...IE has always been a huge pain in the ass.